# Using gcloud cli within a cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, schedule

There are great but still limited set of SDK access to GCP APIs within cloud function SDKs. e.g. Node.

I want to call `gcloud` cli within a cloud function. Is this possible? e.g.

`gcloud sql instances patch my-database --activation-policy=NEVER`

The goal is nightly shutdown of an SQL instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should use the [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/libraries). If you're using the Python runtime for example you'd had 'google-api-python-client==1.7.8' (for example) to your requirements file and on the respective [client library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sqladmin/v1beta4/python/latest/) you would use the method [instances.patch](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sqladmin/v1beta4/python/latest/sqladmin_v1beta4.instances.html#patch) with the appropriate parameters.

Hope this helps.

Also you have here a working example with the Python runtime, just be sure to edit the 'projid' and 'instance' variables accordingly.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service = build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4')

projid = '' #project id where Cloud SQL instance is
instance = '' #Cloud SQL instance

patch = {'settings': {'activationPolicy':'NEVER'}}

req = service.instances().patch(project=projid, instance=instance, body=patch)

x = req.execute()
print(x)
```